# Why am I getting a 404 for chat rooms?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, 404-not-found

Suddenly I can't access any chat rooms.

Example:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

[image]

Did someone trip over a network cable or accidentally push something they were testing to the production servers?

Comment: Seems you're in there right now?

Comment: It seems to be back up again. I'll leave this question here for an official explanation of what happened.

Comment: That's not even one of our 404 pages. Are you sure you're not behind some acting-up proxy?

Comment: @balpha: No, I'm not behind a proxy. Are you sure one of your load balancers or caches couldn't have displayed that error page?